# Run a specific launch from task in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

When I open the project on `vscode`, I want it to start running in debug mode.
I have a lunch configuration in the `launch.json` file which starts the project in debug mode when I hit "F5".
In addition, I have a `vscode` task with the `"runOptions": {"runOn":"folderOpen"}` option.
the problem is: as much as I can tell, tasks can only run commands or other tasks.
is it possible to configure a command to run a specific "launch from the `launch.json`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config)

In the extension settings (`settings.json`) you setup a command to start a launch config

```
"launches": {
    "StartLaunch": "Start Launch (Project Folder)"
}
```

In you `tasks.json` call this task with a variable `${command:commandID}` somewhere in the task strings.

```
${command:launches.StartLaunch}
```

You can use a dummy [shell echo task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had to figure out something similar (minus the launch on folder open). I've put together an example for your specific question for posterity.

To run a `launch.json` config on folder open, you are on the right track in trying to get a task setup first.

Assuming the config is setup like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
      "request": "launch",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `tasks.json` should be setup like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "launch: debug",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "${input:launchDebug}",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "launchDebug",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "workbench.action.debug.start",
      "args": ["Launch Program"]
    }
  ]
}
```

That's it! You should see the task run on next open of the workspace and/or by running the task via the command palette.

**Bonus**:

My use case was needing a convenient way to run a debugger as a task, but I also setup one to support a select and start tasks when there are multiple launch configs. This also works when there are [compounds](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) as well!

`tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "launch: debug",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "${input:launchDebug}",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "launch: select debug",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "${input:selectLaunchDebug}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "launchDebug",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "workbench.action.debug.start",
      "args": ["Launch Program"]
    },
    {
      "id": "selectLaunchDebug",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "workbench.action.debug.selectandstart"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this can still help someone!

**References**:

- [VSCode Inputs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables)
- [VSCode workbench command Id](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/browser/debugCommands.ts#L64) to [start a debug session by label](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/browser/debug.contribution.ts#L132).

Answer (score 0):

This can work if you're happy to launch the currently selected one just as F5 would do when you aren't already debugging:

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "my-debug-trigger-task",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.debug.start}"
    },
  ]
}
```